Attempt at solving $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n!} dx$
This problem was found at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJ6j1DXS4AU.
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n!} dx$$
First, I sought to find the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}$. I did this in a rather unconventional way, so this may be where I went wrong. My solution was as follows:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}= \frac{\sin(nx)}{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$
$\frac{\sin(nx)}{\infty}$ is the average of all $\sin(nx)$ in the infinite sum (essentially factoring out the $\sin(nx)$ term). The average would be equal to the average of the sin function, which has a range of $0 \le \sin(x) \le 1$. The average of this range is $\frac{1}{2}$, resulting in this continuation:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}= \frac{e-1}{2}$$
Returning to the integral, we can plug in the solution:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} (\frac{e-1}{2}) dx= \frac{e-1}{2}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}dx$$
However, I cannot continue from here because this integral does not converge. I looked at the solution from the video mentioned above, and the answer was $\frac{\pi}{2}(e-1)$, implying that $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}dx = \pi$, which is impossible. The solution in the video was done much differently, but it was far too advanced for me to understand at my current level.
Could someone please explain what I did wrong, as the result from the infinite sum was very close to the actual answer, but the integral did not converge? Was there some sort of workaround I missed, or was there a fault in my process?

I don't think the part regarding the average is rigorous

You cannot factor the $\sin(nx)$ term out of the series, and the average value of $\sin(x)$ would be $0$.
Indeed, $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}dx=\pi$ would not make sense.
The series within the integral is in terms of $x$, so it is not necessarily valid to approximate it with a constant.

I don’t agree with OP’s average of all $\sin (nx)$, instead, the integral can be directly evaluated using compound angle and IBP as in my solution below.

Wild stuff there!

I realized the sine range was also wrong. Thank you for all the kind responses.

Not sure if this identity actually simplifies anything, but $\sin(x)\sin(nx)=\frac{\cos((n-1)x) - \cos((n+1)x)}{2}$.

We can deal with the integral using compound angle formula followed by integration by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n x)}{n!} d x \\
= & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \sin (n x)}{x^2} d x \\
= & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n-1) x-\cos (n+1) x }{x^2} d x \\
= & -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_0^{\infty}[\cos (n-1) x-\cos (n+1) x] d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
= & -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{(n-1) \sin (n-1) x-(n+1) \sin (n+1) x}{x} dx \textrm{ (via IBP)} \\
= & -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!}[(n-1)-(n+1)] \frac{\pi}{2} \cdots (*)\\
= & \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2}\left(e-1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $(*)$ using the formula:$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)}{x}dx =\frac{\pi}{2} . $

We can avoid IBP

Thank you for your interesting suggestion, let me try later.

@Claude Leibovici, I had just posted another solution using double integral.  Have a look if you have time.

Here it is another way to calculate the corresponding series:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n!} & = \text{Im}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{n!}\\
& = \text{Im}\exp\left(e^{ix}\right)\\\\
& = \text{Im}\exp\left(\cos(x) + i\sin(x)\right)\\\\
& = \exp\left(\cos(x)\right)\sin\left(\sin(x)\right)
\end{align*}

Double integral
As @Claude Leibovici kindly suggested, we can do it without integration by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n-1) x-\cos (n+1) x}{x^2} d x \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_0^{\infty} \int_{n-1}^{n+1} \frac{\sin (y x)}{x} d y d x \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_{n-1}^{n+1} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (y x)}{x} d x d y \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_{n-1}^{n+1} \frac{\pi}{2} d y \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}(e-1)
\end{aligned}
$$

You could have used $$\int\frac{\cos (n-1) x-\cos (n+1) x}{x^2} ,dx=$$ $$-\frac{2 \sin (x) \sin (n x)}{x} +(n+1) ,\text{Si}((n+1) x)-(n-1),   \text{Si}((n-1) x)$$
